# Take out a few words from a line, php

Tags: php

If I have a line containing words like: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Is there anyway that I could fwrite to extract out two words from within and put it in a new text file? I would like to have the two words: brown fox

How can I do that with php script?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the logic when you choose the two words?

Comment: Which words should the program choose? The 3rd and 4th words? Words "brown" and "fox" in the order they appear? Every word that starts with b or f?

Comment: There are many ways to do this depending on exactly what you want.  You could split the line into separate words with `explode()`.  You could use regular expressions.  What do you need to do?

Comment: Pentium - I just wanna have an example of what type of functions / way that I can do this.

Comment: Juhana - Yes, the words brown and fox only.

Comment: Syrion - Can I have an example of how to do it? Thanks! =)

Comment: "Yes" isn't really an answer to an open-ended question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, type this:

```
$fName = "out2.txt";
$fHandle = fopen($fName, 'w');
fwrite( $fHandle, "Brown Fox" );
fclose($fHandle);
```

That should do the job, until you provide a better explanation of your problem.

Seriously, check if Brown Fox can be found in the file, and if found simply do what I wrote up there.

To get 3rd and 4th word, do this for a line containing the text:

```
$line = explode(" ", $line);
fwrite($fHandle, $line[2]." ".$line[3]);
```

Comment: Yes, the word brown fox can be found in the file, but is there any other way of doing it? Like ... getting the 3rd and 4th words, without typing 'brown fox' in it? Thanks.